# Display Object name from Array of Array in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-ngmodel, angular-services, angular-ng

I'm confused on how would i display the categories.name in array of object. I want to display in the first td.

[image]

```
<tr *ngFor="let innerItem of project.project_services">
    HERE--> <td>{{ innerItem.categories.[name]}</td>
    <td>{{innerItem.service.sku}}</td>
    <td>{{innerItem.service.name}}</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<tr *ngFor="let innerItem of project.project_services">
    <td *ngFor="let categoryItem of innerItem.categories">{{categoryItem.name}</td>
    <td>{{innerItem.service.sku}}</td>
    <td>{{innerItem.service.name}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Now I have edited the answer by adding one more *ngFor on categories

Comment: @GraySingh: Sure, and if this answer has worked for you then please approve my answer too.

Comment: It says you can accept answer in 6 minutes. Ill just wait for it